# accessing clipboard data in Firefox when we copy and past

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, cross-browser

I am facing issues while accessing clipboard data from javascript in Fire Fox. My issues is i am pasting data which greater than max length of test filed and trying to validate that we pasted text > max length. For this i am trying to read data from clipboard. But i am unable to access it from FF.

Can any one plz provide the solution.

I tried with below code

```
 $("#abc").bind("paste", function (event) {
    var clpBoardData = window.clipboardData.getData("Text");
    }   

});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$("#abc").bind("paste", function (event) {
    var clpBoardData = event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData("Text");
    console.log(clpBoardData);
    }   
});
```

u cant use 'window.clipboardData' on crome, firefox and opera

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to this  https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/964543